# Mysql group_concat query gives error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have get this error
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `) ) AS name FROM (`resource_details`) JOIN` location`ON`reso_dtail_location`' at line 3**

Code as follows

```
  $this->db->select('loc_country,CONCAT(s_name , ":", GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT dist_name
    ORDER BY dist_name ASC
    SEPARATOR "," ) ) AS name ');
  

  $this->db->from('resource_details');
            //join
            $this->db->join('location','reso_dtail_location=loc_id');        
            $this->db->join('go_state', 'go_stste_id = loc_state', 'left');
            $this->db->join('go_country', 'num = loc_country', 'left');
            $this->db->join('go_dist', 'id = loc_district', 'left');
            $this->db->where('loc_id !=1 AND loc_id !=2');
            $this->db->group_by('country_name');
            $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: not sure about what CodeIgniter creates as complete statement, but you probably want to add `s_name` to your `GROUP BY` list

Comment: For complex operations, it is recommended to use `$this->db->query('YOUR PLAIN QUERY HERE');` [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query like below

```
$this->db->select('loc_country,CONCAT(s_name , ":", GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT dist_name ORDER BY dist_name ASC SEPARATOR "," )) AS name',false);
$this->db->from('resource_details rd');
            //join
            $this->db->join('location l','rd.reso_dtail_location=l.loc_id');        
            $this->db->join('go_state gs', 'gs.go_stste_id = l.loc_state', 'left');
            $this->db->join('go_country gc', 'gc.num = l.loc_country', 'left');
            $this->db->join('go_dist gd', 'gd.id = l.loc_district', 'left');
            $this->db->where('l.loc_id !=',1);
$this->db->where('l.loc_id !=',2);
            $this->db->group_by('gc.country_name');
            $query = $this->db->get();
```

Two changes from your existing query **add false in select statement** and **where condition is wrong** and also used the alias where you have two many joins in a single query.

*Note : I have added alias as per my understanding you can change it as per your database structure*

**For adding a query in from clause**

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;    
$this->db->select('ft.id,GROUP_CONCAT(ft.Name separator ",") as ColumnName',false);
    $this->db->from('(select id, concat(Name, ":", GROUP_CONCAT(Value separator ",")) as Name from mytbl group by id, Name) ft');
    $this->db->group_by('ft.id');
```

remember if you want to add join above query than use **ft* for alias

Comment: select id, group_concat(`Name` separator ',') as `ColumnName`
from
(
  select id, concat(`Name`, ':',
  group_concat(`Value` separator ',')) as `Name`
  from mytbl
  group by id, `Name`
) tbl
group by id;                                                                                                  i want this query in codeigniter  how i can convert it plz help

Comment: so you want to add another query in your from statement. is this you want ?

Comment: @riya : is this a different questions because the questions you asked and the comment doen't match with what you want. ?  if it is a different than i suggest please first complete this questions and put a new questions for new things.

Comment: use `echo $this->db->last_query()` and put your query output

Comment: put `echo $this->db->last_query()` after `$this->db->get()` than it will show last_qeury

Comment: @riya: checkout the updated answer. I think you need to add `$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;` before your query.